# Joomla 3.x.x jdoc include

Tags: joomla

I am new to Joomla, I am using the version 3.4.8, and I am tasked to modify and edit some pages.Now I have this page inside index.php, where I want to edit since this images did not show up except the messages.I cant find position-7 file inside module category..

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-7" style="xhtml" /><!--where is this -->
```

I looked up inside modules folders in all Joomla directory but I cant find it.

When Inspect Google, I found this

```
  <div class="moduletable">
    <ul class="category-module">
       <li>
         <a class="mod-articles-category-title " href="/news/277-2016-train-the-trainer-workshops-aerial-lifts-lockout-tagout">2016 “Trainer”  Aerial Lifts &amp; Lockout/Tagout</a>

      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="mod-articles-category-title " href="/news/176-emergency-bulletin">Emergency Bulletin</a>

  </div>
```

How to edit this>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get this in your default template folder and file will be `index.php`

And for more information read this doc - https://docs.joomla.org/Jdoc_statements